# Accessing model data members in action? Need cast?

Tags: ember.js

This must be a simple concept, but it seems to be assumed rather than covered...
I have a simple model, journal, and component, journal-list:

```
<select class="form-control" id="journal" onchange={{action 'showJournal' value="target.value"}} >
<option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Periodicals:</option>
  {{#each model as |journal|}}
    <option value="{{journal}}"> {{journal.name}}</option> 
  {{/each}}
</select>
```

and action:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    editstate: Ember.inject.service('edit-state'),
    actions: {
        showJournal(journal) {
            this.get('editstate').selectedJournal = journal;
            alert('got ' + journal.name);
            this.sendAction('displayJournal', journal);
        }
    }
});
```

That selected value is not, as far as I can tell, useful, and the journal instance in the action isn't either.  Ember knows it's type Journal (e.g. `<em-journalapp@model:journal::ember385:3>`), but I can't access the members via, e.g., journal.name, journal.get('name') or anything else I've thought of.

I can pass in journal.id instead, and see it.  But if I look up the model from the store, the variable again isn't useful.

Is there some magic to casting or storing model data in variables and getting it back out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will encourage you to use [ember-power-select addon](http://www.ember-power-select.com/).

When you say `<option value="{{journal}}">` this will be rendered in html like `<option value="[object object]">` you can't store object for html attribute.
So you need to include the `id` like this `<option value={{journal.id}}>` you can get the selected object through findBy method from options list.

[Created this twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/b8964880e4b5ac8bbd56a4d18b45a134?openFiles=routes.application.js%2C) for this.

application.hbs

```
<select class="form-control" id="journal" onchange={{action 'showJournal' value="target.value"}} >
<option value="" disabled="disabled" selected={{unless editState.selectedJournal.id 'selected'}}>Periodicals:</option>
  {{#each model as |journal|}}
    <option value={{journal.id}} selected={{if (eq editState.selectedJournal.id journal.id) 'selected'}}> {{journal.name}}</option> 
  {{/each}}
</select>
```

application.js route file,

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(){
    return [{id:'1',name:'BBC'},{id:'2',name:'TV'}];
  }
});
```

application.js controller file,

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  editState: Ember.inject.service(),
  appName: 'Ember Twiddle',
 actions: {
        showJournal(journalId) {                        
            this.set('editState.selectedJournal',this.get('model').findBy('id',journalId));
          console.log('Yes ',this.get('editState.selectedJournal'));
        }
    }
});
```

As you maintained state is service so I also did it.
edit-state.js service file

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Service.extend({
  selectedJournal:{},
});
```

Comment: Thank you.  So what you're saying is, "Yep, that's because the model doesn't survive a visit to HTML-land."  Makes sense.